# How to detect if an Android phone has a built-in equalizer?

Tags: android, equalizer

Up until now I was using the following code

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(AudioEffect.ACTION_DISPLAY_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_PANEL);
return (intent.resolveActivity(PodcastAddictApplication.getInstance().getPackageManager()) != null);
```

But for some reasons, this returns false on devices even though they have a built-in equalizer (I know this because calling startActivityForResult(intent) on the previous intent works)

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Are you trying to figure out if the device as the Equalizer effect available or if it also has a UI control panel to control the Equalizer?

Comment: Also the reason what you're doing doesn't work is probably because you're targeting Android 11 and package visibility was limited: https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility

Comment: Yes I'm targeting a recent version of Android, but even adding  <package android:name="android.media.action.DISPLAY_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_PANEL" /> doesn't help here. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Also this works fine on some devices running Android 12, so it looks like this package visibility restriction isn't causing this